# How to display only one key if i hold the key down in the textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is There any possible way to display only one character when a key is pressed **DOWN** for a longer period of time what I mean is when I press lets say 's' **DOWN** for a longer period of time I want only 's' displayed and I don't want this to happen 'ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss....' .

And whit out using this method because this brings on the problem that if a user types fast and presses two keys at the same time only the second one will get displayed for example if I press down 'k' and press down whit out letting 'k' go the 'p' only the 'p' will get displayed.

```
var textarea='';

document.getElementById('textareaID').onkeydown=keydown;
document.getElementById('textareaID').onkeyup=keyup;

function keydown () {

this.value=textarea;

}

function keyup () {
textarea=this.value;
this.value=textarea;

}
```

And please do not say using counters because it doesn't work for some reason believe me I have tried for the last 3 days.

http://toki-woki.net/lab/long-press/ this is what i am basically trying to do but I cant understand how the part where you hold the key down and only one is displayed out is done and of course if i press a key and while the key is down i press another one both of them get displayed rest is easy.

So i would love and explanation its driving me crazy.

Comment: I am in college this is for learning purposes.

Comment: On a serious note, and this is just guessing without any testing whatsoever, if you have a boolean, like var keyReleased=false; and then make it true in your keydown, then wrap the logic in your keyup with if(keyReleased)

Comment: please please don't do it. Don't ever change the input behavior in your app. It will only confuse your users. If, for some reason motility diseases for example, a user needs it, there are system-wide settings to change the behavior.

Comment: If i use or not i still wish to understand how its done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright I think I got it.

1: On keydown cancel the input to the textarea.

2: On keyup put in the clicked letter.

```
document.getElementById('textareaID').onkeydown=keydown;
document.getElementById('textareaID').onkeyup=keyup;

// keydown is run more than once if held down hence "ssssssss"
function keydown (event) {
    // cancel input
}
// since the keyup event is only fired once we will do most of the work here
function keyup (event) {
    // insert input
}
```

Here is the code (there are comments so you can see what's going on):
http://jsfiddle.net/NerfAnarchist/gXVuC/

Comment: This prints characters on `keyUp` only though. It modifies the normal way any text field is used.

Answer (score 1):

As commenter PA pointed out, I think this is bad practice to alter native behavior of textbox or textareas. See your other options before doing this.

...But ***IF*** you have to do it:

You can use the `keyDown` event to let the event pass on condition that it is followed by a `keyUp` event. The following code is [based on this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/remibreton/GWDEy/).

```
​document.getElementById('box').addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
    // Superglobal window.characterPrinted to detect if the event has already fired.
    if(window.characterPrinted != true){
        window.characterPrinted = true;
        this.value += String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
})​​​​​​​​;

document.getElementById('box').addEventListener('keyup', function(event){
    // Reset superglobal
    window.characterPrinted = false;
});
```

Note that this code uses `addEventListener` and `preventDefault`, which is not guaranteed to work in older browsers. You'll need to bind events using different methods. (I'm looking at you, IE7).

Another note: this code ***adds*** to the `textarea`. Therefore, if a `delete` key pressed, it will try to **add** a `delete`, which does nothing. You can do an `event.keyCode` filtering to see if it's a letter before fiddling with the `event` itself, much like Michael suggested.